# Python list comprehension with lambda function transformation

Tags: python, lambda, pyspark, list-comprehension

Suppose I have for simplicity this small corpus consisting of just 2 lines.

```
'This is first'
'This is second'
```

In order to use it to my reduceByKey spark method I need to have the following output:

```
[((u'This', u'is'), 1), ((u'is', u'first.'), 1), ((u'This', u'is'), 1), ((u'is', u'second.'), 1)]
```

but with the code I wrote bellow I took the following format (more lists). Check my desire solution is inside one 'list' but the output i get has more (depending on my number of words per sentence)

```
[[((u'This', u'is'), 1), ((u'This', u'first.'), 1)], [((u'is', u'first.'), 1)], [((u'This', u'is'), 1), ((u'This', u'second.'), 1)], [((u'is', u'second.'), 1)]]
```

How can modify this in order to get what I want.

```
couples = lines.map(lambda s : s.split(" ")).flatMap(lambda s: [[((s[i],s[j]), 1) for j in range(i+1 , len(s))] for i in range(len(s)-1) ])
```

In case someone don't know pyspark but good python I want to modify this part:

```
lambda s: [[((s[i],s[j]), 1) for j in range(i+1 , len(s))] for i in range(len(s)-1) ]
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: try: `lambda s: [((s[i],s[j]), 1) for i in range(len(s)-1) for j in range(i+1, len(s))]`

Answer (score 0):

In python, there's no such thing as return value expansion. Which means you need to explicitly write out your return values. Which means the lambda has to return a list. The list flattening has to be taken care of on the outside. It can be implemented in different ways. For example,

```
reduce(lambda a,b: a+b, lines.map(...).flatMap(...))
```